# Flutter package - simple_barcode_scanner 0.0.5 not working on windows

Tags: windows, flutter, package, barcode

Hi I am currently using the flutter package simple_barcode_scanner 0.0.5 in order to scan a QR code on my (flutter) windows application. The project compiles, camera permission is requested etc, however I am not receiving any result back when scanning a QR code. Can someone kindly confirm if they are experiencing the same result and/or if there is an additional setup/configuration step that I might be missing in order for this package to work.

Kind regards,
Alecia

Answer (score 0):

there is an open [issue](https://github.com/CodingWithTashi/simple_barcode_scanner/issues/8) for that, you can add the error or issue which you are facing with steps to reproduce in the same thread.